# Software to calculate Fst from sequence data

Tags: bioinformatics, population-biology, software, population-genetics, fst

I'm looking for a software to calculate Fst from 3 loci DNA data of individuals from a metapopulation. I don't have any prior on the population structure (have no idea of the number of subpopulations for example)

I've been looking at [FSTAT](http://www2.unil.ch/popgen/softwares/fstat.htm) but it doesn't run on MAC.

Do you have any easy alternative?

Comment: it should be pretty easily implementable in perl or python.

Answer (score 2):

If You are familiar with R, try package [adegenet](https://github.com/thibautjombart/adegenet/wiki/). It contains very nice tutorials explaining its usage, including the very R basics. If You require graphical interface, install [RStudio](https://www.rstudio.com/) - very nice front-end for R. There are more possibilities how to calculate Fst in R, but adegenet is one of the most powerful genetic packages there.